# Determine at what points the complex function $f\left(z\right)=e^{2x}\cos3x+ie^{3x}\sin2y$ is differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, cauchy-riemann-equations

Determine at what points the complex function
$$f(z)=e^{2x}\cos3y+ie^{3x}\sin2y$$

is differentiable.

---

The function is differentiable at $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ if $f$ is defined on a neighborhood of $z_0$ contained in $D_f=\mathbb C$ (in this example this condition is satisfied) and $\lim_{z \to z_0}\frac{f\left(z\right)-f\left(z_{0}\right)}{z-z_{0}}$ exists, but here computing the limit is difficult, so what's the the alternative solution?

And generally when we are asked to find all points that a specific function is differentiable at such points what should we do?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy--Riemann equations? Do they hold here?

Comment: @user1040538 According to your comment, there is a typo in your $f(z)$ that is $\cos 3y$.

Comment: I think the derivatives are still incorrect, the imaginary part is independent of x and the real part is independent of y.

Comment: I assume you're using $x$ and $y$ to denote the real and imaginary parts of $z$?

Comment: @user1040538 According to your comment in #2, do you mean $f\left(z\right)=e^{2x}\cos3y+ie^{3x}\sin2y$?

Comment: @user1040538 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: And if you don't get an acceptable answer, you can comment as to what more needs to be done to satisfy you.

Answer (score 6):

We know $f$ is differentiable wherever the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold, that is, $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$

$f\left(z\right)=e^{2x}\cos3x+ie^{3x}\sin2y$, so let
$$
\begin{align*}
u(x,y)&=e^{2x}\cos3x\\
v(x,y)&=e^{3x}\sin2y.
\end{align*}
$$
Now we find
$$
\begin{align*}
u_x&=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{2x}\cos3x)=2e^{2x}\cos 3x-3e^{2x} \sin 3x\\
v_y&=\frac{d}{dy}(e^{3x}\sin2y)=2e^{3x}\cos 2y\\
u_y&=\frac{d}{dy}(e^{2x}\cos3x)=0\\
v_x&=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{3x}\sin2y)=3e^{3x}\sin 2y,
\end{align*}
$$
So we want to know where
$$
\begin{align*}
2e^{2x}\cos 3x-3e^{2x} \sin 3x&=2e^{3x}\cos 2y\\
0&=-(3e^{3x}\sin 2y).
\end{align*}
$$
For the first equation use Wolfram-Alpha (don't waste your time doing this by hand) and got

$x=\frac{1}{3} (2\pi n_1+\pi)$, $y=\frac{1}{2} (2 \pi n_2 - \cos^{-1}(-e^{(1/3(-2\pi n_1-\pi))}), n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}.$

For the $2$nd equation, we just need to find where $\sin 2y=0$, so we know that $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $y=\dfrac{\pi n}{2}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The version in the question body has $\cos 3y$ in $u$. I suspect a typo in the question title that went unnoticed. This may also explain why the asker was not happy with your solution.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, too bad he was not communicating about it.

Comment: Yeah. They should have commented on that.